# How to reverse y-axis label using plot function in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, time-series, label

I use the code below to plot 3D graphs in R.

`plot(pred,zlab="Something_1", ylab="Something_2",xlab="Something_3")`
[image]

How can I reverse the y-axis label ("Something_1)?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I didnt realize this was possible in the generic `plot()` function, could you share `dput(pred)` so that we can see what structure you're working with? Typically `persp` is used for this type of figure

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by dput(). I am not familiar with this command. However, pred stands for a matrix resulted from crosspred() function of dlnm package. It is ussually used in epidemiological science, to study the effect of an exposure (i.e. temperature) and an outecome (i.e. morbidity/mortality) during a time period.

Comment: This might work:

`plot(pred, axes=FALSE)
axis(1)
axis(2)

zlabs=axis(3, labels=FALSE, tick=FALSE)
axis(3, at=zlabs, labels=rev(zlabs))`